# Remove rating for a single track in Winamp

Tags: winamp, music-management, rating

How do you completely remove the rating from a track in Winamp?  I see in my library that there are tracks without ratings, but I can't seem to explicitly set a track with a '0' rating.

Comment: Long time since I used Winamp. Isn't doing it via Explorer a possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the rating from the Playlist. Select all the tracks you want to apply the rating to, right-click, and "Rate Items" is the last menu item. "No rating" is a possible selection.

Comment: Yeah, I found that one, too.  Thanks though.  You get the check mark, good sir.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I was looking for this solution, found your post, was unrating some files using the method you'd posted, and later found a much less time consuming and tricky method. Thought I'd post to save the next guy some hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!  There is a small space (a pixel or two) just to the left of the rating column in the Media Library where clicking assigns a '0' rating.